# Standardizing paper size

Tags: bills, philippines

Could someone submit a bill proposing to standardize the paper size for a country?

What would be the considerations to pursue this?

Comment: Do you mean the Philippines do not have items in **ISO 216** (which is a copy of the A and B series part of DIN 476) available? Maybe JIS P 0138-61 (which in turn is mostly a copy of the A series of ISO 216  and the C series of DIN 476 with slight alterations to the B series)? The different sized ANSI/ASME Y14.1 ("Letter") or CAN 2-9.60M? [According to Wikipedia the de-facto standard in the Philippines should be the ANSI/ASME Y14.1, which includes Letter.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Prevalent_default_paper_size.svg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Politics.SE and appears to be about the process for enacting a law.

Answer (score 2):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Both the government and private Members may present a bill in the House of Commons. However, the process for a private Member's bill to receive time and consideration on the Order Paper is subject to procedural hurdles, such as [random selection](https://www.ourcommons.ca/procedure/our-procedure/PrivateMembersBusiness/c_g_privatemembersbusiness-e.html).

From there, the bill would be pursued subject to ordinary political considerations, such as its practicality, cost-benefit analysis, Parliament's understanding of the bill's constitutionality (including division of powers), public opinion, etc.